# TF_REPEATED_DATA error with robot_localization ukf package

Tags: ros, navigation, tf2, time, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Running ROS Noetic. I am receiving the following error on transforms published by UKF node from robot localization:

> Warning: TF_REPEATED_DATA ignoring data with redundant timestamp for frame base_link at time 1597872121.936377 according to authority /ukf

I see this error popping up wherever the transform is being used (e.g., rviz) as well as in the UKF node's console output.

I did not have this issue with a hand-coded transform node. I am a bit uncertain how the UKF node handles and publishes transforms internally so hard for me to think about what could be causing this, here is what i know:

- Timestamps on incoming odometry (only source I am using right now for testing) are being set correctly
- Does not occur with any other transforms published by other nodes
- We have multiple developers working on multiple different PCs, Some are VMs, some are physical installations. The error occurs repeatably on all of them so I don't believe it is any sort of system clock error or similar

Sorry for lack of additional detail, not sure what will be most helpful to share. Please let me know and I will update post.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/359968/tf_repeated_data-error-with-robot_localization-ukf-package/) by [rb](https://answers.ros.org/users/13396/rb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 130 on 2020-08-19

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We are aware, its an ongoing discussion in this ticket: https://github.com/ros/geometry2/issues/467

You probably haven't done anything wrong and generally speaking things should work OK in spite of the warnings.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the 'tf' is depreciated and we can use tf2_ros for the transformation.
Also plugins itself publishes the tf and joint states, so you have to disable them too while working, in order to avoid repeated tf publishing.

---

Originally posted by [dcornerboy](https://answers.ros.org/users/76687/dcornerboy/) with karma: 21 on 2021-06-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2